# How to write function if variable ends with...?

Tags: magento-1.9, if

I have this function:
if ($ order-> getData ('customer_email') == 'fvzqmufneovrezmv@marketplace.amazon.it')

I do not want to put a specific email but emails ending in '@marketplace.amazon.it'

How to proceed ?
I tried
if ($ order-> getData ('customer_email') == '@marketplace.amazon.it')

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$customerEmail = $order->getData('customer_email');
if (preg_match("/@marketplace.amazon.it$/", $customerEmail)) {
   // do something
}
```

---

***LE based on commnent***

if you want to check if the email is one of marketplace.amazon.it OR marketplace.amazon.de then this is the code:

```php
$customerEmail = $order->getData('customer_email');
$needles = ['@marketplace.amazon.it', '@marketplace.amazon.de'];

foreach ($needles as $needle) {
   if (preg_match("/{$needle}$/", $customerEmail)) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
What if I also want @ marketplace.amazon.de?

Comment: check my updated answer above

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance

Comment: you're most welcome. please consider accepting this as solution if it suits your needs. cheers and good luck!